# Separate function result in different rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dropdown list (Sheet1) that takes information from another sheet (Sheet2), I've created the following function to display the rows from which the information is coming from (given that I have multiple rows with the same information/name):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF(Sheet2!A2:A133=Sheet1!B2, ROW(Sheet2!A2:A133)-ROW(Sheet2!A2)+1, ""))
```

The result might come up as something like:

16,17,18,19,20

I want to separate the result in different rows, to something like:

16

17

18

19

20

I've tried using the text to columns feature and then transposing but the feature only reads the function, not the result, is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use FILTER instead: `=FILTER(ROW(Sheet2!A2:A133)-ROW(Sheet2!A2)+1,Sheet2!A2:A133=Sheet1!B2)`